# Can I find a package's peer dependencies on www.npmjs.com

Tags: npm

I have a project that has around 50 packages installed through NPM. After several months of neglect I now need to update most packages, resulting in several mismatching peer dependencies. In order to find the correct combination of package versions I want to see the peer dependencies of all versions of a certain package.

Where on www.npmjs.com can I find a package's peer dependencies?

A package's page shows "dependencies" and "dependents", but I believe these are normal dependencies, not "peer dependencies".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [www.npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/) website doesn't expose *peer dependencies* information. However, this metadata resides at the npm registry endpoint: `https://registry.npmjs.org/`.

Via your command line you can access it by utilizing the [`npm view`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view.html) command. For instance:

```
npm view <pkg_name> peerDependencies
```

<sub>**Note:** You'll need to substitute the `<pkg_name>` part with a real package name.</sub>

The aforementioned command will list `peerDependencies` for the latest version of the given package.

---

> I want to see the peer dependencies of **all versions of a certain package**.

To achieve this you can:

1. Run the following command to obtain all versions for a given package

   ```
   npm view babel-loader versions --json
   ```

   <sub>**Note** Here we check for [babel-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-loader) but this could be any valid package name</sub>

   This will print:

   ```json
   [
     "4.0.0",
     "4.1.0",
     "4.2.0",
     "4.3.0",
     "5.0.0",
     ...
   ]
   ```
2. Then run the following command to obtain the peer dependencies for each version previously listed:

   ```
   npm view babel-loader@4.0.0 peerDependencies --json
                        ^^^^^^
   ```

   prints:

   ```json
   {
     "babel-core": "^4.0.0",
     "webpack": "^1.4.5"
   }
   ```

   Repeat again - similar to before but change the `@<version>` suffix, i.e. `@4.1.0` in the example below.

   ```
   npm view babel-loader@4.1.0 peerDependencies --json
                        ^^^^^^
   ```

   This prints:

   ```json
   {
     "babel-core": "^4.7.0",
     "webpack": "^1.4.5"
   }
   ```

   and so on...

---

### Automate the task:

You may want to consider automating the steps above by creating a *node.js* script as follows. This utilizes the nodejs [`execSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) method to shell out the necessary `npm` commands, however you could change it to utilize the [`exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) method if you want it to run asynchronously:

**script.js**

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const sh = require('child_process').execSync;

const PKG_NAME = 'babel-loader'; // <-- Change the package name.

const destFilePath = PKG_NAME.replace(/\//g, '_') + '-peer-deps.json';

const versions = JSON.parse(sh('npm view ' + PKG_NAME + ' versions --json').toString());

const data = versions.map(function(semver) {
  const pkgVersion = PKG_NAME + '@' + semver;
  console.log('> Fetching peerDependencies info for: ' + pkgVersion);

  const peerDeps = sh('npm view ' + pkgVersion +
      ' peerDependencies --json').toString().replace(/[\r\n]/, '');

  return {
    name: pkgVersion,
    peerDependencies: peerDeps ? JSON.parse(peerDeps) : null
  }
});

fs.writeFileSync(destFilePath, JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

console.log('\nDone !');
```

Then run the following command to invoke the node.js script:

```
node ./path/to/script.js
```

<sub>**Note:** You'll need to redefine the `./path/to/` part as necessary.</sub>

Given the value of `babel-loader` currently assigned to the `PKG_NAME` variable in `script.js` you'll see something like the following logged to your console:

> ```
> > Fetching peerDependencies info for: babel-loader@4.0.0
> > Fetching peerDependencies info for: babel-loader@4.1.0
> > Fetching peerDependencies info for: babel-loader@4.2.0
> ...
> ```

Upon completion it will write a `.json` file to disk named `babel-loader-peer-deps.json`, which includes the following content:

**babel-loader-peer-deps.json**

```json
[
  {
    "name": "babel-loader@4.0.0",
    "peerDependencies": {
      "babel-core": "^4.0.0",
      "webpack": "^1.4.5"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "babel-loader@4.1.0",
    "peerDependencies": {
      "babel-core": "^4.7.0",
      "webpack": "^1.4.5"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "babel-loader@4.2.0",
    "peerDependencies": {
      "babel-core": "^4.7.0",
      "webpack": "^1.4.5"
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

---

#### EDIT: Reducing the number of https GET requests

If you're wanting to reduce the number of https `GET` requests to just one then I suggest utilizing the nodejs builtin [`https.get()`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback) to fetch JSON data from the `https://registry.npmjs.org/` endpoint.

This example gist below will be much faster.

**get-peer-deps.js**

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const https = require('https');

const pkgName = process.argv[2];
const myName = path.basename(__filename);

// Check the package name has been provided
if (!pkgName) {
  console.log('\x1b[40;37m%s\x1b[0m \x1b[40;31m%s\x1b[0m', myName,
      'ERR!', 'Missing package name argument');
  process.exit(1);
}

const fileName = pkgName.replace(/\//g, '_') + '-peer-deps.json';
const destFilePath = path.join(path.dirname(__filename), fileName);
const endPoint = 'https://registry.npmjs.org/' + encodeURIComponent(pkgName);

// Request JSON from npm registry endpoint.
https.get(endPoint, function(resuest) {
  console.log('> Fetching peerDependencies info for: %s...', pkgName);
  var response = '';

  resuest.on('data', function(chunk) {
    response += chunk;
  });

  resuest.on('end', function() {
    processJsonResponse(response);
  });

}).on('error', function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});

/**
 * Processes the JSON response to extract the necessary metadata and saves
 * resultant JSOn to disk.
 * @param {String} data - The JSON response from the npm registry.
 */
function processJsonResponse(data) {
  const versions = JSON.parse(data).versions;
  const semvers = Object.keys(versions);

  const peerDepsInfo = semvers.map(function(semver) {
    const current = versions[semver];
    return {
      name: current.name + '@' + current.version,
      peerDependencies: current.peerDependencies || null
    };
  });

  fs.writeFile(destFilePath, JSON.stringify(peerDepsInfo, null, 2), function(err) {
    if(err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('> Done. Saved result to:\n  %s', destFilePath);
  });
}
```

**Usage:**

Then run the following command via your command line tool to invoke `get-peer-deps.js`:

```
node ./path/to/get-peer-deps.js babel-loader
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Note:** When invoking `get-peer-deps.js` it's necessary to provide the package name as an argument. In the example above we pass in `babel-loader`. This can be replaced with whichever valid package name you prefer. For example in the next example we pass in `@angular/forms`:

```
node ./path/to/get-peer-deps.js @angular/forms
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The resultant `.json` file will be formatted as described previously and will be save to the same directory where `get-peer-deps.js` resides.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Too bad that the website cannot be used this way, if I understand NPM dependencies correctly, normal dependencies are installed automaticly but peer dependencies have to be installed manually, meaning peer dependencies is exactly where a website could be usefull.


Your script is very nice! It gives an error though when used on packages that have a forward slash in it though. For instance I tried it on "@angular/forms". Made it work by changing the "destFilePath" to "output.json" though.

Comment: Good catch regarding scoped packages (i.e. those with `/` in their name) - I've edited the answer to provide a fix. It now replaces any `/` in the name with `_`. Given `@angular/forms` the resultant file will be named `@angular_forms-peer-deps.json`.

Comment: Nice! I've been experimenting and found you can use wildcards in the version of the package you request info for. This means you can get all versions with     `npm view @angular/forms@*.*.* peerDependencies`.  You might want to adjust you're script accordingly because the current version takes a while to run if the package has a lot of versions.

Comment: Using wildcards such as `npm view @angular/forms@*.*.*` (with or without the `--json` flag) doesn't produce valid JSON data - so it can't be parsed. If you're wanting to reduce the number of `https GET` requests to the npm registry I suggest you explore developing your own _nodejs_ script that uses the builtin [`https.get()`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback) (or some other existing npm pkg) to fetch the JSON from the `https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular/forms` endpoint, then try manipulating the data returned to see if you can extract what you need.

Comment: Or using bash run a `curl` command, For instance `curl -X GET https://registry.npmjs.org/%40angular%2Fforms` then use a command line JSON parser such as [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) or [json](https://github.com/trentm/json) to manipulate the data and extract what you need.